# Lookup a Name and replace with an ID Number from another Table

Tags: sql

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this but if anyone could help it would be great

I have two tables one is created with information and i need to replace the Names "Lead Gen TM" pulled with the ID Number from a "Users" Table.

Here is the Code I have so far yes most of this code wont be relevant to what I'm asking but I don't know where to put the code so I can change the Name to the ID Number.

```
    SELECT
         m."Id" as 'Meter Id',
         m."Meter Name" as 'Meter Name',
         m."Amount" as 'Amount',
         si."Supplier External Name" AS 'Contracted Supplier',
         si."Supplier Internal Name" AS 'Supplier Internal Name',
         CAST(sh."Modified Time" AS DATE) AS 'Signature Date',
         
            CASE
                 WHEN m."Type"  = 'New Business' THEN 'Acquisition'
                 WHEN m."Type"  = 'Renewal' THEN 'Renewal'
                 WHEN m."Type"  = 'Existing Business' THEN 'Renewal'
                 ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Sale Type',
         
            CASE
                 WHEN m."which meter"  = 'Electricity' THEN cast(m."contract end date elec" + 1 as date)
                 WHEN m."which meter"  = 'Gas' THEN cast(m."contract end date gas" + 1 as date)
                 ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Contract Start Date',
         
            CASE
                 WHEN m."which meter"  = 'Electricity' THEN cast(m."new contract end date elec" as date)
                 WHEN m."which meter"  = 'Gas' THEN cast(m."new ced gas" as date)
                 ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Contract End Date',
         m."Lead Gen New" as 'Lead generated',
         m."Closer New" as 'Lead Closed',
         m."Lead Gen TM" as 'Lead Gen TM',
         m."Lead Gen Office" as 'Lead Gen OP',
         m."Closer TM" as 'Closer TM',
         m."Closer Office" as 'Closer OP'
FROM  meters m
LEFT JOIN "Commission Ledger" cl ON m."Id"  = cl."Parent Meter Id" 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd0 ON wd0."Date"  = today() 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd1 ON wd1."Date"  = yesterday() 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd2 ON wd2."Date"  = (today() -2) 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd3 ON wd3."Date"  = (today() -3) 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd4 ON wd4."Date"  = (today() -4) 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd5 ON wd5."Date"  = (today() -5) 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd6 ON wd6."Date"  = (today() -6) 
LEFT JOIN "Working Days" wd7 ON wd7."Date"  = (today() -7) 
LEFT JOIN "Supplier Ts&Cs Code" code ON m."Id"  = code."m.Id" 
LEFT JOIN "Supplier Info" si ON code."Supplier Id"  = si."SupplierId" 
LEFT JOIN "Supplier TCs Links" tcs ON tcs."Unique Code"  = code."Code" 
LEFT JOIN "Stage History" sh ON m."Id"  = sh."Meter Name"
     AND    sh."Stage"  = 'Sent for Lock in'  
WHERE    ((cast(m."Meter Sold Date" as date)  = (
    case
         when wd1."Working Day?"  = 1 then yesterday()
         when wd2."Working Day?"  = 1 then today() -2
         when wd3."Working Day?"  = 1 then today() -3
         when wd4."Working Day?"  = 1 then today() -4
         when wd5."Working Day?"  = 1 then today() -5
         when wd6."Working Day?"  = 1 then today() -6
         else today() -7
     end)
 AND    m."Which Meter"  in ( 'Gas'  , 'Electricity'  )
 AND    m."Amount"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Amount"  > 0
 AND    si."Supplier External Name"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Lead Gen New"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Closer New"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Lead Gen TM"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Lead Gen Office"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Closer TM"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    m."Closer Office"  IS NOT NULL
 AND    cl."Parent Meter Id"  IS NULL))
```

If anyone can help it would be great.

My "Users" table will look like this.

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Full Name_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3249587691234 | Richard | Lee | Richard Lee |

And I need to replace the Lead Gen TM

| Lead Closed | Lead Gen TM | Lead Gen OP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1448832000208720000 | Richard Lee | Craig Greener |
| 1448832000208450000 | Andrew Parkes | Renewals |
| 1448832000221090000 | Andrew Parkes | Renewals |
| 1448832000208720000 | Richard Lee | Craig Greener |
| 1448832000208720000 | Richard Lee | Inbound |
| 1448832000208720000 | Richard Lee | Craig Greener |
| 1448832000208720000 | Richard Lee | I&C |

Comment: Can you kindly share some example data just to help one understand the relationship between the data.

Comment: Have you tried a JOIN the same way as  `.. JOIN "Supplier Info" si ..` ?

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. I'm guessing that 90% of the sql you've provided is irrelevant to your actual question and causes confusion rather than clarity